# Guest-agent vs Spice agent

Tags: qemu, spice

which is the difference between the guest agent **qemu-ga-x64.msi** and the spice agent = couple **vdservice + vdagent** for a windows guest ?
are they exclusive ou complementary ?

Answer (score 3):

Complementary.

- qemu-ga handles things like shutdown, rebooting vms, freezing and thawing filesystems (for live backups)
- spice agent handles device redirection (I think), cutting and pasting in and out of VMs, smooth mouse movement inside vm-viewer, and so on.